# Linking exposed port of docker with with the default nginx port

Tags: nginx, docker

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk update
RUN apk add nginx 
RUN apk update
RUN cp index.html /var/lib/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 8080
```

Now, how can I access the file index.html on lets say port 9000 on localhost? I got puzzled. Please ask if I am not clear. Just an outline to solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main application is nginx so start from an nginx Dockerfile and simply copy your index.html to it.

Assuming that you have `index.html` in your local directory (where the Dockerfile is located).

```
FROM nginx:1.10-alpine
COPY ./index.html /var/lib/nginx/html
```

Build using

```
docker build -t mywebserver:latest .
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` file could look like:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mywebserver:
    image: mywebserver:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And build the containers using

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The `command` could also be skipped but it's a good practice to include the actual command in the service definition.

Comment: The content of index.html is available on port 80 inside container which can be accessed from external port 8080. But how to run the 8080? I mean how to know container ip?

Comment: I am running command `sudo docker run -d -p 8089:8080 mydocker`

Comment: If you've built `mydocker` the way I describe `mywebserver` above, you can just do `docker run -d -p "8080:80" mydocker`. nginx listens to port 80 by default. The container will be reachable at port 8080 on **the host**.

Comment: Sorry, if its getting hard for me to explain. As I have exposed port 8080 of docker container, the index.html file should be available on lets say http://docker:8080 but how to achieve this?

Comment: The container has its own networking separate from the host. That's probably what's confusing you. When you do `docker run -d -p "8080:80" --name mycontainer myimage`, a container named `mycontainer` is created inside the host. The code inside that container listens to port 80 but only other containers on the same internal network can communicate to it at that port. By specifying `-p "8080:80", docker creates a bridge to the outside. Connections outside the host can access your container at its port 80 by connecting to the **host** at port **8080**.